# Browser navigation not working with react router v5 using BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building a web app with react on codesandbox.

I have 2 navigational components, both function components, one is the header and the other one in the footer.
I'm using a `Switch` to show different pages between the header and footer.

The navigation changes the URL and the switch does his job showing me the right page, the only problem is that the changes are not updating the history of the browser, or overwrites it maybe (???), I don't know.

I already tried coding in a button to call a function that does this:

```js
history.goBack();
```

It works as it should but the browser button does not.
When I navigate with the navigation menu, pages change but the back-button of the browser remains "grey"/"unclickable".

So the question is: How do I get the browser navigation (forward and back button of the browser) working?
I learned that `BrowserHistory` should take care of it without no additional code, am I wrong?

**-- Following are just some extra info that may/may not be related/significant --**

I tried using a simple Link on my navigation like this:

```
<Link to="/Services">Services</Link>
```

Also I tried using `history.push` like this with an `onClick` handler function:

```js
const history = useHistory();

function handleChangePage(pageUrl) {
  history.push("/" + pageUrl);
}
```

On click event that triggers `handleChangePage`:

```
<h2 className="headBarMenuItem" onClick={() => handleChangePage( "Services")}>
 Services
</h2>
```

This is how I have set up the `BrowserRouter` and the `Switch` inside the app component:

Index.js is set up like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

App (function component) is set up like this:

```
<div className="App">
  <Header />
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/Home" component={Homepage} />
      <Route
        path="/Services"
        component={InfluencerMarketingPage}
      />
      <Route path="/Contacts" component={ContactPage} />
      <Route path="/Projects" component={ProjectPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

Footer Navigation:

```
<div className="footerMainMenu">
  <h4>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <Link to="/Projects">Case History</Link>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <Link to="/Services">Services</Link>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <Link to="/Contacts">Contacts</Link>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <Link to="/Aboutus">About Us</Link>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Dependencies are:
react 16.12,
react-dom 16.12,
react-router-dom 5.2,
react-scripts 3.0.1

I got it working the day before posting this question by just adding `react-router@5.2` as a dependency even if I didn't need it, it was working with my footer navigation.
Today I added the header and noticed that the browser navigation was not working anymore, I tried removing and adding `react-router` as a dependency and then also tried downgrading to `react-router-dom@4` but no changes.
Even if I remove the new header component and do the same testing by adding and removing react-router dependency, still no changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have an actual event that triggers your handleChangePage function. Try adding that function to an onClick() on each page where ever the user would click a link to get to a new page.

Then to handle the forward and back buttons you would add

```
function previousPage() {
history.goBack();
```

and for the button

```
onClick={previousPage}
```

Same for the forward button you would use

```
history.goForward()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I just updated the question with a code snippet that included my call of the function hanndlePageChange. About your answer: I'm just trying to make the browser navigation work. I don't have a back button "coded in", i tried doing this anyway and it works. Clicking a button that calls histoy.goBack works but the browser back button still does not, even tho BrowsereRouter should handle this on it's own.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question before but I understand what you are trying to resolve now. From what I can see the issue is likely to be inside of Routes. If you could show your routes and paths it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks again, i updated the question with the routs and included my footer navigation too.

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved my problem.

The browser buttons are now working on every device/browser, I am 99% sure that the problem was caused by having codesandbox and the full page of the app open in the same chrome window (different tabs but same window).

By opening a different window of chrome (NOT different tab) or by opening the web app page in another browser everything works just fine.

The problem is ultimately caused by some kind of conflict between codesandbox and the full page of the app in the same window of the chrome browser.

P.S.
Looks like a very specific problem but hopefully, it is helpful to someone.